# libgdx - bmfont custom font not drawing?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

hello the below code is trying to draw a custom font as a label. whenever i draw it with debug mode on i get a green box around where the text should be displaying but nothing comes up. i have never used a custom font, only the ones already installed on my computer. however, i do have the ".png" in my assets folder so i don't see why its not drawing.

no errors in the stacktrace, a picture below to help describe the problem.

```
public void show() { 


          stage = new Stage();
            float delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
           stage.setDebugAll(true); // Set outlines for Stage elements for easy debug

            BitmapFont white = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("hazey.fnt"), false);
            white.setScale(2);
            LabelStyle headingStyle = new LabelStyle(white, Color.BLACK);
            Label gameoverstring = new Label("game over", headingStyle);
            gameoverstring.setPosition(100, 100);
            stage.addActor(gameoverstring);






    }

    // Called every frame so try to put no object creation in it
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) { 

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor((float)96/255,(float)96/255,(float)96/255, 1f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        System.out.println("hey");


        stage.act(delta);

        stage.draw();



    }
```

http://imgur.com/C1NOUbK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used your code more or less verbatim and it appears to work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlqvl.png

Your font might be busted, try:

```
BitmapFont white = new BitmapFont();
```

to use default one and check if it works. If it does, make sure that your font contains all the required glyphs. Also don't scale fonts, they will look horrible.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be a similar problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046163/textureatlas-issue-with-libgdx)

How are you running your project? If it's from within an IDE on the desktop, have you remembered to set the current working directory to be android/assets?

If not, then it won't find the font files, which could cause the issue you see.

Appologies for posting this as an answer btw - I don't have enough reputation to post it as a comment.