# TextureAtlas issue with libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I keep getting null pointer exceptions when I try and use TextureAtlass with this libgdx project. 
game.atlas and game.png are under android/assets

```
game.png
size: 1024,1024
format: RGBA8888
filter: Nearest,Nearest
repeat: none
bunny_head
  rotate: false
  xy: 2, 44
  size: 122, 82
  orig: 122, 82
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
```

Load the atlas with

```
TextureAtlas atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("game.atlas"));
head = atlas.findRegion("bunny_head");
```

This is my Exception log

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.fancylancy.game.WorldController.initTestObjects(WorldController.java:49)
    at com.fancylancy.game.WorldController.init(WorldController.java:39)
    at com.fancylancy.game.WorldController.<init>(WorldController.java:33)
    at com.fancylancy.game.Game.create(Game.java:20)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:143)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
```

Comment: Pretty hard to say without knowing the specificts.. At which line is the nullpointer exception thrown? It might have nothing to do with textureatlas..

Comment: Its thrown at the point head is set to atlas.findRegion("bunny_head");

Comment: Are you sure? I don't see how the atlas object would be null, as its initialized just on previous line, even if the texture atlas object wasn't initialized correctly from the file game.atlas, it wouldn't be null

Comment: Thats why I'm at a loss. I've been having a lot of strange issues. Think it has to do with the book I've been using as a guide. Seems its very out dated and from the reviews just plain bad. Think I'm going to find my self a newer/better book and start over. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I guess the `Exception` is thrown in the line above. It's not the `findRegion`, but the `Gdx.files.internal`, which does not find your "game.atlas". I guess it's because your assets are not linked correctly. You should use the `GDX-Setup.jar` or follow [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Manual-project-setup#asset-folder-setup) instructions.

Comment: could also look to have the game.png image that accompanies, .atlas file in the directory

Answer (score 0):

How are you running your project? If it's from within an IDE on the desktop, have you remembered to set the current working directory to be android/assets?

If not, then it won't find game.atlas which could cause the issue you see.

Appologies for posting this as an answer btw - I don't have enough reputation to post it as a comment.